# Issues with column alignment

Tags: c++, alignment

I was able to align my columns but I am having trouble with my coding where my "%" will not connect to the percent variable.

This is my coding for the output/alignment:

```
//HEADER
    outFile << left << setfill(' ') << setw(15) << "Member Name" 
                << setfill(' ') << setw(20) << "Portion Achieved" 
                << setfill(' ') << setw(12) << "Grade (%)" 
                << setfill(' ') << setw(15) << "Letter Grade" 
                << setfill(' ') << setw(15) << "Comment" << endl;

 while (count <= 6)
    {
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin >> student.name;
    cout << "Points Achieved: ";
    cin >> student.points;
    cout << "\n";

        decimal = (student.points/60);
        percent = decimal*100;

        outFile << left << setfill(' ') << setw(15) << student.name 
                << setfill(' ') << setw(20) << decimal 
                << setfill(' ') << setw(12) << percent << " %"
                << setfill (' ') << setw(15);
```

This is how the output looks:

```
Member Name    Portion Achieved    Grade (%)   Letter Grade   Comment        
Min            0.166667            16           %F              Sorry, you did not pass :(
Carmela        0.333333            33           %F              Sorry, you did not pass :(
Jayson         0.5                 50           %F              Sorry, you did not pass :(
Kristin        0.666667            66           %D              Needs Improvement!
Mae            0.833333            83           %B              Well Done!     
JT             1                   100          %A              Excellent!
```

VS how I want it to look:

```
    Member Name    Portion Achieved    Grade (%)   Letter Grade   Comment        
    Min            0.166667            16%         F              Sorry, you did not pass :(
    Carmela        0.333333            33%         F              Sorry, you did not pass :(
    Jayson         0.5                 50%         F              Sorry, you did not pass :(
    Kristin        0.666667            66%         D              Needs Improvement!
    Mae            0.833333            83%         B              Well Done!   
    JT             1                   100%        A              Excellent!
```

Comment: Try `<< percent << setw(12) << " %"` instead of `<< setw(12) << percent << " %"`

Comment: @tobi303: That won't work.

Comment: It worked in making the # and % stick, but now my last two columns are misaligned.

Comment: All Tobi's suggestion does is add ten spaces around the `" %"`, always, regardless of how long the percentage value is.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing what you told it to do. The integer `percent` value is given a "width" of 12 characters. Anything that comes after, comes after. There is no code here to "connect" anything together, nor does any such feature exist in C++ stream speak.

You're probably going to have to pre-construct `percent + " %"` (pseudocode) into a string, then use that single string as the column value. Perhaps:

```
<< setfill(' ') << setw(12) << (std::to_string(percent) + " %")
```

Otherwise, drop `setw` and write *n* spaces yourself. To do this, you'll need to work out how "long" your stringised `percent` text is, add 2 (for " %") then subtract the lot from 12. Write `std::string(n, ' ')` to the stream. Yuck!

Comment: Something along the lines of `<< setfill(' ') << setw(12) << std::to_string(percent) +" %"` should work.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Could you further explain? I tried making a new string grade in which [ grade = percent + "%" ]. But when I output grade it does not do the #% it outputs something totally different.

Comment: What is that "totally different" thing? What is `grade`? I cannot help you without knowing exactly what it is that you've done. Did you try the code I gave you?